# In Scala, do immutable Lists share memory?

Tags: scala, recursion, immutability, tail-recursion

Thinking of immutable lists and their usage in recursive functions, I am wondering if `List`s ever share memory. For example,

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val k = -2 :: -1 :: 0 :: l
k: List[Int] = List(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Do `l` and `k` share any memory here, and thus act something like a slice, where the only difference between them are their pointers to the first and last elements, or does the `::` operator actually have to clone the list `l`?

I am curious about this because if they *do not* share any memory, would that not have dire consequences for memory and CPU usage in recursive functions, that, e.g., end in calls to themselves with `list.tail` or `elem :: list` as parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Scala Docs:

List implements structural sharing of the tail list. This means that many operations are either zero- or constant-memory cost.